# Concatenate Main Group to Subgroup via FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, xml, concatenation, for-xml-path

I can concatenate multiple rows to generate a comma separated value in a single row by using FOR `XML` `PATH` like such:

```
TMonth  Location    Degrees
Jan     Tokyo       7.0
Jan     New York    -0.2
Jan     Berlin      -0.9
Jan     London      3.9
Feb     Tokyo       6.9
Feb     New York    0.8
Feb     Berlin      0.6
Feb     London      4.2

SELECT t.Location, STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(5), s.Degrees)
FROM MonthlyTemps s
WHERE s.Location = t.Location
--FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS CSV
FROM MonthlyTemps AS t
GROUP BY t.Location
```

RESULTS:

```
Location     CSV
Berlin     -0.9,0.6
London     3.9,4.2
New York   -0.2,0.8
Tokyo      7.0,6.9
```

Now, I really need the results to be as such (i.e. the "main" group concatenated onto the front of the "subgroup"):

```
CSV
Berlin,-0.9,0.6
London,3.9,4.2
New York,-0.2,0.8
Tokyo,7.0,6.9
```

I've attempted a few different queries to no avail.  I know it's right there staring me in the face, but I need an extra pair of eyes to help me.  Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string concatenation  and sub-query join two column with `','`. Hope this work.

```
select Location + ',' + aa as 'CSV' from 
(
SELECT t.Location, STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(5), s.Degrees) as aa
FROM MonthlyTemps s
WHERE s.Location = t.Location
--FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS CSV
FROM MonthlyTemps AS t
GROUP BY t.Location
) as temp
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!  I knew it was something quite straightforward.  Note that I had to edit the first line to concatenate to the full CSV output.  Many thanks again!